# What is the meaning of the following SQL Server declaration: datetime2(7)?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

Inside a SQL Server query, there is: `datetime2(7)`.
I know `datetime2`, but I don't understand `(7)`.

Can you explain the meaning of `(7)`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
datetime2 [ (fractional seconds precision) ]
```

It's the fractional seconds precision according to the MSDN documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx

This is the microsoft example of 4:

```
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2(4) = '12-10-25 12:32:10.1234';
```

So I would assume that 7 would be:

```
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2(7) = '12-10-25 12:32:10.1234567';
```

Comment: Can you have a datetime2(0) if you dont care about nanoseconds

Comment: Yes, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql precision can be  0-7.